# Slider issue - 1st image disappears after 1st cycle of slides

Tags: slider, advanced-custom-fields

On this homepage: https://tachpro.com/ the first slide appears fine on load, but then when the slides revolve and it comes around again, the image disappears. It's a slider from ACF

Any ideas? Presume a Javascript / index issue possibly,but can't see it.

Thanks in advance!

Tried rearraging / clearing cache etc